# Add Text at the bottom of the last ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I want to add a `TextBox` after the last item of a `ListView` (or at the bottom **inside** of the `ItemsPresenter` of a `ListView`).

At the moment I am defining a template for the last `ListViewItem` and I am using a converter to be sure which element is the last one.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource LastItemInContainerConverter}}" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="#DCDCDC" Background="#eeeeec" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <TextBox>Hello!</TextBox>
            </StackPanel>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

But the items are in a `ObservableCollection` and I am getting problems about the layout refreshing upon adding and removing items.

Any approach or idea how can I define that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I find the solution.

```
            <ListView.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <!-- this is needed -->
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Hello!!!</TextBlock>
                        </Grid>

                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Template>
```

Comment: It will break the Virtualizing